# how can I generate a report for custom events for google analytics 4 report api?

Tags: google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

I was using UA analytics like this before:

```
// javascript event
ga('set', 'dimension1', artist);
```

```
# Ruby report params
metric = Metric.new(expression: 'ga:hits')
dimension = Dimension.new(name: 'ga:dimension1')
order_by = OrderBy.new(field_name: 'ga:hits', sort_order: 'DESCENDING')
range = DateRange.new(start_date: '30daysAgo', end_date: 'yesterday')

# Report request
rr = ReportRequest.new
rr.view_id = VIEW_ID
rr.metrics = [metric]
rr.dimensions = [dimension]
rr.order_bys = [order_by]
rr.page_size = NUM_ARTISTS + 1
rr.date_ranges = [range]

grr = GetReportsRequest.new
grr.report_requests = [rr]

response = @client.batch_get_reports(grr)
```

Then migrated to GA4:

```
// javascript event
gtag('event', 'artist', {
    'artist': artist
});
```

I can see the GA4 website Reports > Engagement > Events the events collected.

```
Parameter Name
Artist
Parameter Value    Count
The Cure           3529
New Order          2480
...
```

(numbers made up)

I am using the same json credentials file that I was using before.

How can I retrieve those values with the API report? I tried tweaking the params I had for UA but no results.

If I change my ruby code to this, it complaints with `Google::Apis::ClientError (badRequest: Invalid value 'eventCount' for metric parameter.)`

```
metric = Metric.new(expression: 'eventCount')
dimension = Dimension.new(name: 'customEvent:artist')
order_by = OrderBy.new(field_name: 'eventCount', sort_order: 'DESCENDING')
range = DateRange.new(start_date: "#{last_days+1}daysAgo", end_date: 'today')

# Report request
...
```

And If I use the [GA4 query explorer](https://ga-dev-tools.web.app/ga4/query-explorer/) with:

```
Metrics: eventCount
Dimensions: customEvent:artist
Order by: eventCount desc
```

I get this:

```
customEvent:artist  eventCount
(not set)           9962
```